# Smoothness and field of fractions

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry, algebraic-geometry, modules

If $k$ is an integral domain and $A$ is a Noetherian finitely presented $k$-algebra for which $A \otimes_k Q(k)$ is a smooth $Q(k)$ algebra, then can it be deduced that $A$ was initially smooth over $k$?

Comment: You seem to be asking whether generic smoothness implies smoothness?

Comment: I don't know what that is .... (well I can imagine but formally I have no experience with the concept)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To expand on Zhen Lin's comment:

Let $R$ be an integral domain, $A$ a finitely presented $R$-algebra, $Q$ the fraction field of $R$.

Then:

- to say that $A$ is smooth over $R$ can be reinterpreted geometrically as saying that the morphism of affine schemes $\operatorname{Spec} A \rightarrow \operatorname{Spec }R$ has nonsingular schemes as fibres over each point.
- to say that $A \otimes_R Q$ is smooth over $Q$ means geometrically that the fibre of $\operatorname{Spec} A \rightarrow \operatorname{Spec }R$ over the *generic* point $\operatorname{Spec} Q$ of $\operatorname{Spec }R$ is nonsingular.

The second does not imply the first.

As a simple example, let $R=k[t]$, $A=k[x,y,t]/\left<xy-t\right>$. Geometrically, $\operatorname{Spec} A \rightarrow \operatorname{Spec} R$ is a family of affine conics in $\mathbf A^2$ (with coordinates $x,y$) parametrised by the affine line $\mathbf A^1$ (with coordinate $t$). The generic member of this family is indeed a nonsingular conic. However, the fibre over the point $0 \in \mathbf A^1$ is the conic $xy=0$, which is singular.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answerwas extreemly insightful Asal! :) (& Zhen :) )

Comment: But I am curious is there a condition for which Generic smoothness will imply smoothness?

Comment: I think our examples indicate that this condition will be almost never satisfied.

Comment: @CSA: in fact I think that given a nonsingular affine scheme over $Q$, other than trivial examples, you can _always_ find a family of affine schemes over $\operatorname{Spec} A$ with some singular fibres (say, by an appropriate blowup). So no condition on $Q$ or the generic fibre will make this true.

Comment: Cool!  Thank you very much Asal and Martin :D

Answer (score 4):

$\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ is not smooth (for example since $\Omega^1_{\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]/\mathbb{Z}} \cong \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]/(2)$ is torsion), but $\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}] \otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{Q} = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is smooth (in fact, étale).

Comment: As always your feedback has been of paramount help, thanks Martin :D